# Changing datetime format without changing the locale in Java

Tags: java, datetime, lotus-notes

In my Java program, I'm creating datetime to a String in format:

```
"dd/mm/yyyy 02:00:00 AM GMT"
```

Then I use `createDateTime(String date)` method from Lotus ([method doc](http://notes.helsinki.fi/help/help8_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/e831c96b97f5f19c8525731b004b03c8?OpenDocument)) but the format of the datetime is changed to:

```
"mm/dd/yyyy 02:00:00 AM GMT"
```

because of regional settings on a Windows machine where is program running.
Locale is set to `English.US` that has different date format. I can manually change this setting, but this is system wide.

Is there a way to change that date format only for this program without changing locale/date format of locate in system?

Comment: It's a java program? Then you can set System properties at startup by passing -D options to the java vm

Comment: What is the type of your datetime object?

Comment: What do you mean "format … is changed to"? Apparently you passes String data to Lotus Notes which created a date-time object from that String. Notes will present that object’s data (your Sting is long gone) any way it wants without regard to your Java-based data feed. As-is, I will be voting to close this question as it is unclear and without enough information.

Answer (score 0):

Read this article, http://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/java-parse-date/

You have to use SimpleDateFormat object. This object constructor get a format string and use parse function get a string date parameter.